# How to connect the derby client in JDBC in a client server model in between two devices connected by a ethernet cable?

Tags: java, jdbc, network-programming, client-server, derby

Right now my project runs well in Netbeans and uses the **derbyclient.jar** in JDBC for database on a single system. 
I want to deploy it as a **client-server model** by connecting my laptop to another one via an Ethernet cable.

- i want one laptop running the project code
- the second laptop running the derby database

both the system should interact with each other in this way.
how to do that?

Comment: What, specifically, do you need help with? The network server on the second laptop needs to run the Derby Network Server with the appropriate arguments to allow the first laptop to access it; the project code needs to specify the network address of the Derby Network Server in its connection URL; the network configuration (firewalls, etc.) need to allow this connection to take place. Which part is causing you problems?

Comment: @BryanPendleton i have no clue how to establish connection between two laptops via ethernet connection. On the client device in netbeans i go to Services>Databases>Drivers>Java DB(Network) and right click to connect. Then a dialog box opens up where i have to enter the host, port, database name(db present on the client side), user name, password. Right now i dont know what to get the IP input in the host section.

Comment: Each machine in a TCP/IP network has its own IP address. Can we assume you are running some version of Windows? You can learn more about Windows TCP/IP configuration here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-tcp-ip-settings#1TC=windows-7